# expected LP_SHFILEOPSTRUCTW instance instead of pointer to SHFILEOPSTRUCTW (python ctypes)

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, win32com

I'm using following code to execute some file system operations (copy/move/rename of files  and folders) on windows.
This code requires pywin32.

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, UINT, LPCWSTR, BOOL, WORD
from ctypes import c_void_p, Structure, windll, POINTER, byref

src = unicode(os.path.abspath(_src_) + '\0', 'utf-8')
dest = unicode(os.path.abspath(_dest_) + '\0', 'utf-8')

class SHFILEOPSTRUCTW(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("hwnd", HWND),
                ("wFunc", UINT),
                ("pFrom", LPCWSTR),
                ("pTo", LPCWSTR),
                ("fFlags", WORD),
                ("fAnyOperationsAborted", BOOL),
                ("hNameMappings", c_void_p),
                ("lpszProgressTitle", LPCWSTR)]

SHFileOperationW = windll.shell32.SHFileOperationW
SHFileOperationW.argtypes = [POINTER(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW)]

args = SHFILEOPSTRUCTW(wFunc=UINT(op), pFrom=LPCWSTR(src), pTo=LPCWSTR(dest), fFlags=WORD(flags), fAnyOperationsAborted=BOOL())

result = SHFileOperationW(byref(args))
aborted = bool(args.fAnyOperationsAborted)

if not aborted and result != 0:
    # Note: raising a WindowsError with correct error code is quite
    # difficult due to SHFileOperation historical idiosyncrasies.
    # Therefore we simply pass a message.
    raise WindowsError('SHFileOperationW failed: 0x%08x' % result)
```

flags are always: `shellcon.FOF_SILENT | shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | shellcon.FOF_NOERRORUI | shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR`

op is for e.g.: `shellcon.FO_COPY`

The problem I have is that sometimes this function gives me error:

```
ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_SHFILEOPSTRUCTW instance instead of pointer to SHFILEOPSTRUCTW
```

especially when dealing with very long paths (e.g. `len(dest)=230`)

What I'm I doing wrong here?

[edit]

There is a `shell.SHFileOperation` but we need to use custom wrapper `SHFileOperationW` to support unicodes.

[edit2]

As Barmak Shemirani wrote, in python3 you can just simply use shell.SHFileOperation and it will work with any special unicode chars.
If I will find a solution to fix this in python2, I'll share it here.

Comment: The above code does not work (imports, variable initializations missing). also `SHFileOperationW` returns an int, indexing it (`[0]`) will trigger an error. I don't have `win32com.shell`.

Comment: @CristiFati install pywin32
Option 1 - install using whl
Download whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32 (in case of problems with page load, go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/ and find link to wheels). Download whl compatible with installer version of python (so v32b if python is v32b, even if the windows itself is v64b).
Install using pip install path\to\whl
Option 2 - install using msi installer
Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/ download latest
Download exe installer
Install it.
The call to [0] was there by mistake, I removed it.

Comment: _src_ and _dst_ are in this example any path you want, in my code this is a func and are passed as arguments.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `shutil` for copying files?

Comment: Also, are you exceeding Windows `MAX_PATH`?

Comment: @MarkTolonen No, max we have is len(dest)=230; in some cases shutil on windows doesn't behave exactly like windows would, and I need to "mimic" win operation for testing purpose

Comment: `shell.SHFileOperation` works in version 3 with Unicode.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani did you try with e.g. unicode('tmpvziliy马]сâↄṈஅаƏŁĞƘ.txt', 'utf-8')? I'm using python 2.x, and this is where shell.SHFileOperation fails for me. If it indeed works on python 3.x, that would be the final kick to migrate to python 3 ;)

Comment: shell.SHFileOperation supports unicode in version 3. There is no unicode() function in version 3 though -- By the way, did you make sure the script file is saved in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 3 you can use [`shell.SHFileOperation`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/shell__SHFileOperation_meth.html) with [`SHFILEOPSTRUCT`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/SHFILEOPSTRUCT.html) which will also append double null terminator when needed.

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

shell.SHFileOperation((
    None,
    shellcon.FO_COPY,
    "c:\\test\\test1.txt\0c:\\test\\test2.txt",
    "c:\\test\\ελληνική+漢語+English",
    shellcon.FOF_SILENT | shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | 
    shellcon.FOF_NOERRORUI | shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR,
    None,
    None))
```

Comment: It doesn't support unicodes e.g. chinese, tamil, etc. chars.

Comment: I tested it with Unicode and it works. I tested your `SHFileOperationW` method and it works as well. This is evidently version related. Can you use `win32api.MessageBox` with Unicode?

Comment: Can you try with: unicode('tmpvziliy马]сâↄṈஅаƏŁĞƘ', 'utf-8') and make sure that it actually copies the file? and shell.SHFileOperation returns (0, False)?

Comment: also I'm on python 2.x, are you on python 3.x?

Comment: Yes that's version 3.6, it works with Unicode. You can use `os.path.abspath` directly in `SHFileOperation`